# Subgroup of the braid group $B_n$ generated by $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_{i+1} ^2$ is a free group?

Tags: group-theory, knot-theory, group-presentation, braid-groups

Let $B_n$ be the braid group on $n$ strands, $n \geq 3$. Consider a subgroup $H$ generated by $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_{i+1}^2$. Is $H$ a free group of rank $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $a=\sigma_i$ and $b=\sigma_{i+1}$. Then $b^2ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1} b^{-2}a=1$.

The group generated by the squares $\sigma_{i}^2$ and $\sigma_{i+1}^2$ is known to be free.

Comment: May I know how you come up with this solution? I mean about the strategy to solve these kinds of questions.

Comment: I suspected it was not free (I might have come across a similar problem before) and then just did a brute force computer search for a relator. So I don't really have a helpful strategy!